# One color picker for multiple colors (background, foreground and text)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a color picker that works as intended

HTML:

```
<input id="cyan" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">  
<input id="magenta" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">  
<input id="yellow" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">
```

JavaScript:

```
var colorPicker = document.getElementsByClassName( "colorPicker" );
for( var i = 0; i < colorPicker.length; i++ )
{
  colorPicker[i].addEventListener( "input", function(){
    var cyan = document.getElementById( "cyan" ).value,
        magenta = document.getElementById( "magenta" ).value,
        yellow = document.getElementById( "yellow" ).value;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
    localStorage.setItem( "cyan", cyan );
    localStorage.setItem( "magenta", magenta );
    localStorage.setItem( "yellow", yellow );
  });
}
```

I want to be able to use the same one color picker on the screen, but have a radio button or drop down for selecting other color values to change.

Hope this is clear.  I am new to JavaScript and know it is powerful and flexible.  I just do not know how to make this happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? I have added HTML select element and attached event to it.

```js
var colorPicker = document.getElementsByClassName( "colorPicker" );
for( var i = 0; i < colorPicker.length; i++ )
{
  colorPicker[i].addEventListener( "input", function(){
    var cyan = document.getElementById( "cyan" ).value,
        magenta = document.getElementById( "magenta" ).value,
        yellow = document.getElementById( "yellow" ).value;

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
    localStorage.setItem( "cyan", cyan );
    localStorage.setItem( "magenta", magenta );
    localStorage.setItem( "yellow", yellow );
  });
}

var colorPickerSelect = document.getElementById("colorPickerSelect");
colorPickerSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = colorPickerSelect.value;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cyan" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">  
<input id="magenta" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">  
<input id="yellow" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">  
<br/>
<select id="colorPickerSelect">
  <option>red</option>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vipin,

Thank you very much for your post.  You got me thinking and I figured it out.  The below solution is functioning great.  Just a few more little tweaks are needed to get the exact desired behavior.

HTML:

```
<input id="cyan" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">
<input id="magenta" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">
<input id="yellow" class="colorPicker" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="grabbable" type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="255">

<select id="colorPickerSelect" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="colorPickerSelect( this.value );">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="background">Background</option>
  <option value="titleBackground">Title BG</option>
  <option value="titleText">Title Text</option>
  <option value="border">Border</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function assignColorPicker( )
{
  var type = document.getElementById( "colorPickerSelect" ).value;
  var cyan = document.getElementById( "cyan" ).value,
      magenta = document.getElementById( "magenta" ).value,
      yellow = document.getElementById( "yellow" ).value;
  if( type == 'background' )
  {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
  }
  else if( type == 'titleBackground' )
  {
    document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[1].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
  }
    else if( type == 'titleText' )
  {
    document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[4].style.color = "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
  }
  else if( type == 'border' )
  {
    document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[0].style.border = '1px solid ' + "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
    document.styleSheets[3].cssRules[2].style.color = "rgb(" + cyan + ", " + magenta + ", " + yellow + ")";
  }
}

function colorPickerSelect( )
{
  var colorPicker = document.getElementsByClassName( "colorPicker" );
  for( var i = 0; i < colorPicker.length; i++ )
  {
    colorPicker[i].removeEventListener( "input", assignColorPicker );
    colorPicker[i].addEventListener( "input", assignColorPicker );
  }
}
```